# How can I assign an asterisk to a cell which has been formatted as 'Currency' and is also used as raw data for a Pivot Table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet full of raw data, where I have created a Pivot Table to help organise and manage said raw data.

For the purposes of this question, I would like to use the below image to help illustrate what I am looking to achieve ...

[image]

In the 'Bill Amount' column, I have formatted the cells to display 'Currency'.  I have formatted the Pivot Table to also display 'Currency'.

What I would like to do now is append an asterisk (*) to certain cells within the 'Bill Amount' column, which would also be presented within the Pivot Table without affecting the maths.

**Failed Function Option**

I went to an empty cell and inserted `=C2&"*"`.  The idea being to call the C2 cell entry (£10.00 in the case of the above illustration) and append an asterisk to the entry.  Whilst this worked, it removed the 'Currency' format and thus the '£' from both the cell and Pivot Table.

I also tried the `=CONCATENATE(C2,"*")` approach, which resulted in the same outcome as above.

Is anyone aware on how I would be able to append an asterisk to a cell entry which would also be presented within the Pivot Table without affecting any of the maths?

Comment: Are you looking to apply `*` as cheque printing symbol? Like `$*1000.00` or  `$**1000.00`

Comment: I'm looking up achieve, for example, '£1000.00*'.

Comment: use this  `£#,##0.00\*` as custom format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the asterisk to the cell, you are changing it from a number to a string (i.e., 'text'). What you need to do is change the formatting in both places. You can go into custom formatting and set it to `£#\*,##0.00\*` or something similar. The `\` before the * says you are interested in the character * and not the command.

The [docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68) can help explain more on formatting codes so you can make your own.

Comment: Excellent.  This allows me to use the Asterix, whilst maintaining the 'Currency' format.  Is there anyway I can get this Astertix to appear within the Pivot Table itself?

Comment: Just apply the number formatting to the pivot table like you did for the other cells.

Comment: Oh yes!  Stupid moment ... Tried editing the Pivot Table Cell rather than going through the 'Format Cells' option.  Thanks for your answer, works great!

Comment: Welcome! :D Formatting can do a lot of fun stuff